# Apache POI, using both XSSF and HSSF

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi, xssf, hssf

I have a problem with Apache POI project.

I failed to use `XSSF` and `HSSF` in the **"Same Java Class"**. Which jar should I download or which artifact should I get add into maven?

I want to handle both `xls` and `xlsx` files at the same time. When I get excel version error, I will change the *XSSF to HSSF* or *HSSF to XSSF*.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of doing that, try using the new release of Apache POI 3.7, it has SS package which handles both HSSF and XSSF without worrying about type

Details here: http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html

Comment: First of all thanks for your help.

I checked the page you've mentioned. Ok. I've added the code below in my pom.xml :


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-contrib</artifactId>
            <version>3.7-beta3</version>
        </dependency>


However, in spite of that my Java class still cannot resolve XSSFWorkbook?

There is no problem on HSSFWorkbook();


Workbook[] wbs = new Workbook[] { new HSSFWorkbook(), new XSSFWorkbook() };

Comment: XSSFWorkbook is in groupId: org.apache.poi, artifactId: poi-ooxml

Answer (score 7):

Aside from the "standard" SS package solution, you can also simply use an `if statement` to correctly load the right `workbook format` into an `Workbook interface` object, like so:

```
Workbook workbook; //<-Interface, accepts both HSSF and XSSF.
File file = new File("YourExcelFile.xlsx");
if (FileUtils.getFileExt(file).equalsIgnoreCase("xls")) {
  workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(file));
} else if (FileUtils.getFileExt(file).equalsIgnoreCase("xlsx")) {
  workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(file));
} else {
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Received file does not have a standard excel extension.");
}
```

Comment: And `IWorkbook` if using NPOI

Answer (score 1):

Use the factory instead which handles both xssf and hssf

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;

Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("file"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
    filePath = "C:\Users\user1\workspace\myproject\Excel.xlsx"
    String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(filePath);
    System.out.println(extension);
```