# Issues resolving XSSFWorkbook - Java - POI .jar

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xssf

I'm trying to do work upgrading a Java application to handle .xlsx, using a newer POI library than our existing one. I'm having issues similar to those mentioned in the comments to the answer here: [Apache POI, using both XSSF and HSSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266888/apache-poi-both-xssf-and-hssf-using)

I'm pointing the new ss.usermodel, but it keeps telling me it can't resolve the XSSF workbook declaration:

```
Workbook xlsImport = new XSSFWorkbook();
```

I dug through some of their documentation and saw that XSSFWorkbook isn't a part of org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel. It's a part of org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook. But there's no poi.xssf for me to import. Am I pointing to the wrong thing? I'm using POI 3.7 Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Please disregard. My version of JDK is not supported, as I previously thought. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 38):

You need to include the poi-ooxml jars to get the XSSF library. The poi jar only has the HSSF libraries.

Answer (score 16):

You need to include poi-ooxml jars. You can add it to pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Could you update your answer with newer version of apache poi ooxml?

Answer (score 4):

First you need to include the proper jar files into your libraries, poi-ooxml-schemas-3.8-20120326.jar. You can find these at http://poi.apache.org/download.html.
And you need to add the following link to your java file.

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
```

Answer (score 1):

if you created maven project use below dependency in pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.9</version>
</dependency>
```

otherwise import this in your java file

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;

Comment: Apache POI 3.9 is rather old - why are you suggesting people use an older version not the latest one?

Answer (score 0):

Earlier It was giving error like below when I was using maven dependency , but after using downloaded binary jar files i.e. : "https://poi.apache.org/download.html" of poi of latest version its working fine for me .

```
Getting error saying : "IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.poi.util.POILogger, but class was expected
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationshipCollection.parseRelationshipsPart(PackageRelationshipCollection.java:303)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationshipCollection.<init>(PackageRelationshipCollection.java:163)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationshipCollection.<init>(PackageRelationshipCollection.java:133)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart.loadRelationships(PackagePart.java:570)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.getParts(OPCPackage.java:723)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:302)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:37)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:307)
    at com.glide.platform_ml.regressionTests.classification.ExcelCallTest.readData(ExcelCallTest.java:40)
    at com.glide.platform_ml.regressionTests.classification.ExcelCallTest.main(ExcelCallTest.java:29)
"
```

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65141876/5886712

Earlier It was giving error like below when I was using maven dependency , but after using downloaded binary jar files i.e. : "https://poi.apache.org/download.html" of poi of latest version its working fine for me .

```
Getting error saying : "IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.poi.util.POILogger, but class was expected
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationshipCollection.parseRelationshipsPart(PackageRelationshipCollection.java:303)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationshipCollection.<init>(PackageRelationshipCollection.java:163)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationshipCollection.<init>(PackageRelationshipCollection.java:133)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart.loadRelationships(PackagePart.java:570)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.getParts(OPCPackage.java:723)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:302)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:37)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:307)
    at com.glide.platform_ml.regressionTests.classification.ExcelCallTest.readData(ExcelCallTest.java:40)
    at com.glide.platform_ml.regressionTests.classification.ExcelCallTest.main(ExcelCallTest.java:29)
"
```