# Limitation while generating excel drop down list with Apache POI - can we solve this using xssf rather than hssf?

Tags: java, excel, apache, xssf, poi-hssf

[Limitation While Generating Excel Drop Down with Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655185/limitation-while-generating-excel-drop-down-list-with-apache-poi)

This link solves the problem for an `HSSFWorkbook`. Can we do this for an `XSSFWorkbook` too ?

Comment: Please Refer this >> http://forumsqa.com/question/what-is-the-difference-between-xssf-and-hssf/

Comment: also this >> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266888/apache-poi-using-both-xssf-and-hssf

Comment: Just replace `HSSF` with `XSSF` in that answer's code?

Comment: DVConstraint's cant be used with XSSFDataValidation

Answer (score 0):

`HSSF` is the POI Project's pure `Java` implementation of the `Excel 97(-2007)` file format.

While `XSSF` is the POI Project's pure Java implementation of the `Excel 2007 OOXML (.xlsx)` File format.

`HSSF` and `XSSF` provides ways to `read`spreadsheets `create`, `modify`, `read and write` XLS **spreadsheets**.

They also provide:

1. low level structures for those with special needs
2. an eventmodel api for efficient read-only access
3. a full usermodel api for creating, reading and modifying XLS files

> For Further Reference Please gothrough with [This Link](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/)

Comment: How does this in any way answer the question?